# What is the best way to split data in python

Tags: python, split

I have a basic question about python. I want to split the data like
e.g.

```
    [[3,5],[6, 78],[4,45]]

     3,5,6,78,4,45.
```

I am using split method but is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: You may use this one

    `a = [[3, 5], [6, 78], [4, 45]]
    reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, a)
    or
    [i for j in a for i in j]`

Comment: I'm not sure the marked duplicate applies to what you're trying to do, but it's difficult to tell without a more thorough description. You say "I am using split method but is there any better way to do it ?". Could you show us your code using `split`, so we can see what you're actually trying to do?